# pg_dump can not create directory after increase directory space

Tags: postgresql, backup, ubuntu, pg-dump, postgresql-12

I recently run pg_dump to backup database using this command using user `postgres` : `time pg_dump -j 4 -Fd -Z 3 db_profile -f /backup-nfs/`

Previously, the size of backup-nfs was 100 G. The `pg_dump` worked fine.
Then, the server admin increase it to 200 G. So I run `Pg_dump` again. But this time it is throwing out error : **could not create directory "backup-nfs" : no such file or directory found.**

I can create file and directory just as normal by using `postgres` account. But the `pg_dump` can't

What might be the possible cause ? I have checked the `chown`, its fine. I can also do a command like `"ls-lah"` on the directory and its working fine too.

Updates : maybe I need to share this.

So, then I try many pg_dump combinations.

1. `time pg_dump -U postgres -j 3 -F d -Z 3 -t tbl_test -f /backup/**somefolder**/db_profile.back db_profile`  -- does not work. **ERROR** : Could not open file '/var/lib/postgresql/backup/somefolder/backup.bak : No such file or directory
2. `time pg_dump -U postgres -F c -t profile db_profile -f **>** /backup-nfs/profile.bak`  -- *technically, it works*. I add directive ">". I thought it was working because of the directive. BUT, the file size is 0. So, it does not qualify to be working.
3. I run again #2. -- **ERROR** : `permission denied`. I thought the `">"` was the key, but it is not. Why does not it work ? It was just working a minute ago. Also, I have deleted the files from the previous backup.
4. I try another command without `-f`, just the directive : `pg_dump -h 10.100.8.42 -Fc db_profile -t profile > /backup-nfs/dump.sql` -- ***It works***. The file is created too.
5. I try another one : `pg_dump -h 10.100.8.42 -t jpt_non_pns -d db_profile -f /backup-nfs/dump_directive.bak`  -- ***It works*** as well. The file is created too.

Questions :

1. why does it need different combination of parameters to work ? On my local server, it takes all combinations and still working fine.
2. There was a command that works when executed the first time. Then it did not work the second time eventhough I have cleared the previous backup completely. Why does it behave like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `-f` option is not an existing directory in which your backup will be created, but the name of the backup file or directory that does not exist yet and will be created by the backup. So try something like

```bash
pg_dump -F d -f /backup-nfs/db_profile.back db_profile
```

Here, `db_profile` is the database that is backed up, and `/backup-nfs/db_profile.back` is the directory that is created by the command and will contain the backup.

Comment: yes thanks for the advice. I will try it later on. But, why did the previous command work the first time the directory was created anyway?

Comment: Sure, the directory gets created, but only if it doesn't yet exist and you have permissions on `/`. But then the directory will not contain your backup, but *be* your backup.

Comment: `pg_dump -F d -f /backup-nfs/**db_profile.back db_profile**` The text after "/", what is this indicating? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I have edited the answer to describe that.

Comment: hi. i just tried it. still fail with the same error... @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe , I test it on another server (running on VM) : `time pg_dump -U postgres -j 3 -F d -Z 3 -t tbl_test -f /backup/db_profile.back db_profile` -- Works. Folder `/backup` was already there, pre-created previously using command `mkdir -m  
 777 backup `. 

But the I try : `time pg_dump -U postgres -j 3 -F d -Z 3 -t tbl_test -f /backup/**somefolder**/db_profile.back db_profile` -- ERROR : Could not open file '/var/lib/postgresql/backup/somefolder/backup.bak : No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, exactly. `/backup-nfs` must already be there.

Comment: if I do `ls -la`, the **/backup-nfs** directory says:`drwxr-xr-x`. Is that sufficient enough ?  On the other hand, folder **/backup** the Ubuntu running on VM (the one that can run `pg_dump` successfully) has permission `drwxrwxrwx`@LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Depends on who is the owner, but unless it is your current user, the permissions are not sufficient.

Comment: Allright. I changed the permission. And the original command does not work. But then I put directive like : `time pg_dump -U postgres -F c -t profile db_profile -f > /backup-nfs/profile.bak`. It works, but the size is 0 although I have 2 millions records in there. Technically, it still does not work. But then, I run the command again for the second time (after clearing the /backup-nfs). Another error comes up **"permission denied"**. I am just baffled and confused.  @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: What do you mean "the size is 0"? Are there files in the directory? What is their size? Sure, repeating the backup into the same directory will fail, because the directory is no longer empty.

Comment: the size of the backup file is 0. "repeating the backup into the same directory will fail"  --> Yes. thats why I emptied it first before running it again.

Comment: With `-F d`, there is no single backup file.